# Damage after normal block when base class is marked virtual

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++

I am seeing a strange damage after normal block assertion which goes away when I make the base class non-virtual.

I've narrowed it down to the moment the actual delete call is made (original source has smart pointers but I've traced this to occur as well with just plain simple new/delete).

The strange situation is that this occurs only when the base class is marked virtual; removing the virtual declaration of the base class prevents this error. I know virtual base classes affect constructor and destructor execution order but as my class has only one base class (which is an abstract class acting as an interface) I would imagine initialization order isn't actually changed in this case.

The "interface":

```
class INetworkSender
{
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Finalizes an instance of the <see cref="INetworkSender"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    virtual ~INetworkSender() {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the specified data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">The pointer to the buffer holding the data to send.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The amount of data to send.</param>
    virtual void send(const char* data, size_t length) = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the remote address.
    /// </summary>
    virtual const std::string& address() const = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the remote port.
    /// </summary>
    virtual uint16_t port() const = 0;
};
```

The concrete implementing class:

```
class UdpSender
    : virtual public INetworkSender
{
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UdpSender" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="address">The address to which to send.</param>
    /// <param name="port">The port to which to send.</param>
    UdpSender(const std::string& address, uint16_t port);

    /// <summary>
    /// Finalizes an instance of the <see cref="UdpSender" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    virtual ~UdpSender();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the specified data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">The pointer to the buffer holding the data to send.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The amount of data to send.</param>
    virtual void send(const char* data, size_t length) override;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the remote address.
    /// </summary>
    virtual const std::string& address() const override { return this->m_address; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the remote port.
    /// </summary>
    virtual uint16_t port() const override { return this->m_port; }

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// The socket handle. Note we use a void* to abstract away different OS specific implementations!
    /// </summary>
    void* m_handle;

    /// <summary>
    /// The target address.
    /// </summary>
    std::string m_address;

    /// <summary>
    /// The target port.
    /// </summary>
    uint16_t m_port;
};
```

Finally the code that triggers the assert:

```
    UdpSender* sender = new UdpSender("0.0.0.0", 0);
    delete sender;
```

To be sure it's not anything I'm doing in the constructor, destructor or any method being called i've commented out everything in the class implementation:

```
UdpSender::UdpSender(const std::string& address, uint16_t port)
    : m_address(address)
    , m_port(port)
{
    /*
    */
}

UdpSender::~UdpSender()
{
    /*
    */
}


void UdpSender::send(const char* data, size_t length)
{
    /*
    */
}
```

Have I stumbled on an obscure compiler error? VS2019 (16.10.0), toolset v142, compiling for ISO C++17 standard.

Edit: using the address sanitizer gives a bit more information:

==8416==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch on 0x12135a727100 in thread T1:
object passed to delete has wrong type:
size of the allocated type:   72 bytes;
size of the deallocated type: 80 bytes.

Edit2: same but with non-virtual base class still triggers the AddressSanitizer so I imagine it's not directly related to the class being virtual or not although it does appear to impact the size of the object in memory:

==18300==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch on 0x12746dba3020 in thread T1:
object passed to delete has wrong type:
size of the allocated type:   60 bytes;
size of the deallocated type: 64 bytes.

Comment: FWIW it works for me both ways on MacOS with clang. You shouldn't need virtual inheritance here since there's no diamond.  Can't see anything obviously wrong. Try running Analysis ?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce such assertion failure on VS2019 v16.10.0 (I've tried both x86 and x64, both Debug and Release builds), provided that those two lines (with `new` and `delete`) are the only contents of `main()`. Thus, I suspect there is a memory corruption (like buffer overrun) in some of your other code (not shown here) that occurs before the deletion. This is usually the case with heap corruptions, the clobbering often occurs long before it starts to visibly affect program's behavior or to cause noticeable problems. Please try to create a [mre].

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the "damage" you're seeing?  Is this AddressSanitizer only, or some other concrete effects?  I know you edited for more information, but I don't see the output/evidence of issues.  I don't doubt something is happening, but the exact *original* error message isn't in the post.

Comment: @KevinAnderson there are no observable side effects, release mode works normally and debug mode with address sanitizer reports something is off (actually crahses due to a debug assert on the new/delete size mismatch)

Answer (score 2):

The size differences reported by the address sanitizer eventually led me to the root cause of the problem.

Somewhere in the codebase I was using a struct with a custom packing boundary (4; the default is 8) via the following code:

```
#pragma pack(4)
struct Foo { ... }
```

Any code including the header file for this struct would size any struct/class after this include differently (4byte boundary) than code not including the header file or including the header after a struct/class definition (8byte boundary) leading to structs/classes with two different sizes for the same struct/class.

Obviously the packing should be for THAT specific struct only which is achieved using (MSVC specific I imagine):

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(4)
struct Foo { ... }
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Slightly shorter, you can do this `#pragma pack(push, 4)` to start, and then the pop at the end like you have.  What you have *may* work, but I know what I wrote *does* work.